# Compairing two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists. First list describes the amount of items in 1 complete set. Second list has current inventory. My question is following: how can i calculate, how many possible sets can be created with current inventory?

```
a = [1, 1, 2]  # This equals 1 complete set
b = [9, 12, 19]  # This is the inventory
 
# output should be: sets = 9
```

Comment: `"diamond earrings" * 2` does not do what you think. Try printing out the list to see what you're getting.

Comment: Do you realize that `["diamond necklace" * 9]` gives you `['diamond necklacediamond necklacediamond necklacediamond necklacediamond necklacediamond necklacediamond necklacediamond necklacediamond necklace']`, i.e. one item with the phrase repeated 9 times, not 9 items?

Comment: Ignore the string. 

`a = [1, 1, 2]`
`b = [9, 12, 19]`

Comment: Will this fulfills your condition min(x//y for x, y in zip(b, a))

Answer (score 0):

You can take the minimum of the amount in inventory divided by the amount needed for a set of each item type.

```
min(inventory // required for inventory, required in zip(b, a))
```

Comment: I have shared this in comment.

Answer (score -1):

Transform the list in a list of tuples to facilitate the work with

```
tuple_set = [("diamond necklace", 1), ("diamond ring", 1), ("diamond earrings", 2)]
tuple_inventory = [("diamond necklace", 9), ("diamond ring", 12), ("diamond earrings", 19)]

# put a big number
max_sets = 10000
for inventory in tuple_inventory:
    for item in tuple_set:
        if inventory[0] == item[0]:
            possible_sets = int(inventory[1]/item[1])
            if max_sets > possible_sets:
                max_sets = possible_sets
            break
```